# Header redirect if user agent equals variables using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, header, user-agent

I have a script that must redirect to 403 page if user agent equals variables, but if not - must display normal page. Instead of this the script display only blank page and that's all. Please help me to solve my problem or what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the script:

```
<?php

 //-- Get user agent
 //-- Thanks @creditosrapidos10min for hint about strtolower() 
 $useragent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

 //-- BadBot variable
 $Baiduspider = stripos($useragent, "Baiduspider");
 $DotBot = stripos($useragent, "DotBot");

 //-- BadBot constant
 $BADBOT = ($Baiduspider||$DotBot);

if ($agent == $BADBOT){

    header("Location: ohno/403.php");
    exit;


} else { ?>

 Display home page

 <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used `$user` instead of `$user_agent`.

And according to php manual [php manual on stipos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) you should use triple = like ===.

Here is an example of how it should be.

```
<?php
    //-- Get user agent
    //-- Thanks @creditosrapidos10min for hint about strtolower() 
    $useragent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    //-- BadBot variable
    $Baiduspider = stripos($useragent, "Baiduspider");
    $DotBot = stripos($useragent, "DotBot");

    //-- BadBot constant
    $BADBOT = ($Baiduspider||$DotBot);

    if ($useragent === $BADBOT){

    header("Location: ohno/403.php");
    exit;

    } else { ?>

    Display home page

    <?php }
    ?>
```

Comment: no... === not working.. because after === must be false or true... in my example it must be == ... Tank you for answer...

Answer (score 2):

Try with $HTTP_SERVER_VARS instead of $_SERVER, in order to not to have problems with global variables.

If not, try with strtolower:

```
<?php

 //-- Get user agent
 $useragent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

 //-- BadBot variable
 $Baiduspider = stripos($useragent, "baiduspider");
 $DotBot = stripos($useragent, "dotbot");

 //-- BadBot constant
 $BADBOT = ($Baiduspider||$DotBot);

if ($agent == $BADBOT){

    header("Location: ohno/403.php");
    exit;


} else { ?>

 Display home page

 <?php }?>
```

Comment: thank you very much but still no effect... just redirect all user agent to page 403 (.. you can see it at http://sauna.ho.ua/badbot.php

Answer (score 1):

You're using `stripos` on `$useragent` but you haven't defined `$useragent`, you've only defined `$agent`. Try correcting this and trying again.

Comment: sorry.. my mistake.. i change it ...but still not solve my problem(

Answer (score 0):

Works on my browser! maybe its not the code its your browser? i am using opera browser
[image]

Comment: and your screen shot from my page with script code using ==, not  === ;)... That's ok.. Thank you for answer... Your example work perfect.